# Criando Pontos no Google Maps api com dados utilizando PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, api, google, maps

Estou tentando aprender à mexer e fazer uns mapas usando o google maps API mas eu quero saber se tem e como fazer pra pontuar um mapa automaticamente usando pontos (coordenadas) que foram cadastrados no banco de dados através de um formulário. E caso esses pontos se repitam como colocar um único ponto no mapa com o total de pontos na mesma coordenada na aparecendo infowindow.

Quero fazer algo como o exemplo abaixo:

https://www.ufrgs.br/rscontraaedes/casos-de-dengue-contraidos-no-estado/

Desde já Muito Obrigada

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: Olá. A sua pergunta provavelmente será fechada por ser ampla demais. Só seria possível ter uma resposta com qualidade se o autor mostrasse como construir todo o sistema. Tente implementar o tutorial que está no link que o @RafaelFerreira postou no comentário e se houver dúvidas tente isolar em um assunto específico. Veja esse link para ajudá-lo(la) a contribuir melhor com a comunidade: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask e dê uma lida na central de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Muito obrigada Rafael Ferreira .. eu consegui fazer :D... 
eu só ainda não consegui fazer com que os pontos se repitam colocar-los em um único ponto no mapa com o total de pontos na mesma coordenada na aparecendo infowindow. eu sei que tem o recurso MARKERCLUSTERER.. mas eu gostaria de por o valor na infowindow ...